# 'init' is unavailable when trying to use swift object in objective-c class

Tags: objective-c, swift

I have a swift object but when I try using it in an objective-c class I get `'init' is unavailable`, why is this?

my Swift class is as shown below:

```
import Foundation

@objc public class OsonOptions : NSObject {
    @objc var isWebview: Bool
    @objc var key: String
    @objc var token: String
    @objc var products : Array<String>
    var env: Environment
    @objc var clientName: String
    public init(isWebview: Bool,key: String,token: String,products:Array<String>,env: Environment,clientName: String) {
        self.isWebview = isWebview
        self.key = key
        self.token = token
        self.products = products
        self.env = env
        self.clientName = clientName
    }
}
```

My objective-c class that uses it is as shown below:

```
#import "MyFancyLibrary.h"
#import <OsonWidget/OsonWidget-Swift.h>

@implementation MyFancyLibrary
RCT_EXPORT_MODULE()
RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(greetings:(RCTResponseSenderBlock)callback){

    OsonOptions *osonOptions = [[OsonOptions alloc] init];

    NSString* someString = @"random";
    callback(@[someString]);
}
@end
```

this is the line of code that has the error: `OsonOptions *osonOptions = [[OsonOptions alloc] init];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Oto There are several problems, why your initializer is not visible in obj-c:

1. `init` is not marked as `@objc`
2. `Environment`is probably not representable in objc either

Just an example:

```swift
// For the test purposes
@objc public class Environment: NSObject {}

@objc public class OsonOptions : NSObject {
    @objc var isWebview: Bool
    @objc var key: String
    @objc var token: String
    @objc var products : Array<String>
    var env: Environment
    @objc var clientName: String

    @objc public init(isWebview: Bool,key: String,token: String,products:Array<String>,env: Environment,clientName: String) {
        self.isWebview = isWebview
        self.key = key
        self.token = token
        self.products = products
        self.env = env
        self.clientName = clientName
    }
}
```

Used like:

```c
    OsonOptions* oson = [[OsonOptions alloc] initWithIsWebview:YES
                                                           key:@"key"
                                                         token:@""
                                                      products:@[]
                                                           env:environment
                                                    clientName:@""];
```

If you cannot make `Environment` objc and inheriting `NSObject`, you can consider creating another class, like `EnvironmentInterop` or something, that works in objc, and you can translate it into Environemnt object.

Then declare another init for the objc interoperability sake.

On the other hand - default `init` could not be exposed anyway, since properties won't be initialized. So either you provide default values and declare `@objc init() {}`, or what I wrote above.

Answer (score 2):

According to the Swift initialization rules all properties must be initialized while creating the instance. Therefore the default initializer `init()` is not exposed to ObjC.

You have to use the designated initializer     `init(isWebview:key:token:products:env:clientName:)` or assign default values to all properties.

Comment: how do I use the designated initialiser ` init(isWebview:key:token:products:env:clientName:)` in objective-c

Comment: The init method does not appear in the auto complete suggestion methods

Comment: @Oto-ObongEshiett, I may not show in autocomplete but, once you write all the params correctly, it will accept it.